# Invoke private method from class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Ruby class method and I want to use a private method of an object of this class, but Rails throws an error.

The specific context is: I have a model class Team. I defined

```
def self.to_csv(**options)
    # blah blah blah
    teams = self.all
    teams.each do |team|
         csv_row = team.export_as_csv_row #a private method
         # and it failed here
    end
end
```

I am using Ruby 2.2.1 and Rails 4.2. If I cannot do this, if there any way to protect `export_as_csv_row` from other classes seeing it?

Comment: You can use `send`, but... maybe it'd be better to make the method public since it's apparently designed to not be private.

Comment: I am new to Ruby but isn't private method accessible to this class? or private just means only accessible by same type?

Comment: @JunchaoGu private methods cannot be called with an explicit receiver like you are doing calling `team.export_as_csv_row` where `team` is the explicit receiver. There are a ton of great explanations on what `private` means in ruby. [Here is just one such article](http://devblog.orgsync.com/2013/05/20/private-and-protected-they-might-not-mean-what-you-think-they-mean/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily invoke private methods on any instance using `Object#send` method:

```
team.send :export_as_csv_row
```

More details are available in the [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-send) documentation.

Comment: When creating links, use something more descriptive in the text than "here". Give people an idea where they're going. This is important in both a UI and a SEO way.

Comment: @theTinMan I've noticed your edit. Thanks, for pointing to this :)